# How to render custom Highstock Timeline with Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

We use Higcharts/Highstocks. (great job!)

We need to render in one chart:

- one or many timelines
- the chart navigator
- marking facts flags
- maybe other curves

So we need to use Highstocks

You can see an adaptation of the best base we found here :

http://jsfiddle.net/g4KLk/100/

customrange are representing a duration in seconds
We need to display the navigator in order to be able to zoom on specifiq a timerange

In order to get customrange detailed seconds by seconds, we've had to render a point each second on the last line int the graph.

Any solution to get what we want without having to display a "seconds line" ?
And by the way, is there a solution in order to custom the color of each customrange ?

Regards !

The based JSFidle here :

```js
// WGV chart demo 
$(function() {


    $.getJSON('//www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-ohlcv.json&callback=?', function(data) {

        var inputs = [{
            name: 'Bookmark',
            intervals: [{ // From-To pairs
                from: Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 1, 00),
                to: Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 1, 01)
            }, {
                from: Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 20),
                to: Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 21)
            }]
        }, {
            name: 'Mic 1',
            intervals: [{ // From-To pairs
                from: Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 3, 00),
                to: Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 6, 00)
            }, {
                from: Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 18, 00),
                to: Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 23, 00)
            }]
        }, {
            name: 'Mic 2',
            intervals: [{ // From-To pairs
                from: Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 3, 00),
                to: Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 9, 00)
            }, {
                from: Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 16, 00),
                to: Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 18, 00)
            }, {
                from: Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 42, 00),
                to: Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 44, 00)
            }, {
                from: Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 49, 00),
                to: Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 10, 05, 00)
            }]
        }, {
            name: 'Lights',
            intervals: [{ // From-To pairs
                from: Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 11, 00),
                to: Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 55, 00)
            }]
        }, {
            name: 'Brakes',
            intervals: [{ // From-To pairs
                from: Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 11, 00),
                to: Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 55, 00)
            }]
        }, {
            name: 'Siren',
            intervals: [{ // From-To pairs
                from: Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 11, 00),
                to: Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 55, 00)
            }]
        }];


        // re-structure the tasks into line seriesvar status = [];
        var status = [];
        $.each(inputs.reverse(), function(i, input) {
            var item = {
                name: input.name,
                data: []
            };
            $.each(input.intervals, function(j, interval) {
                item.data.push({
                    x: interval.from,
                    y: i,
                    label: interval.label,
                    from: interval.from,
                    to: interval.to
                }, {
                    x: interval.to,
                    y: i,
                    from: interval.from,
                    to: interval.to
                });

                // add a null value between intervals
                if (input.intervals[j + 1]) {
                    item.data.push(
                        [(interval.to + input.intervals[j + 1].from) / 2, null]
                    );
                }

            });

            status.push(item);
        });

        // split the data set into ohlc and volume
        var volume = [],
            dataLength = data.length;

        for (i = 0; i < dataLength; i++) {

            volume.push([
                data[i][0], // the date
                data[i][5] // the volume
            ]);
        }

        // set the allowed units for data grouping
        var groupingUnits = [
            ['millisecond', // unit name
                [1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 25, 50, 100, 200, 500] // allowed multiples
            ],
            [
                'second', [1, 2, 5, 10, 15, 30]
            ],
            [
                'minute', [1, 2, 5, 10, 15, 30]
            ],
            [
                'hour', [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12]
            ],
            [
                'day', [1]
            ]
        ];

        // create the chart
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                marginTop: 40
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            rangeSelector: {
                enabled: false,
                inputEnabled: false,
                selected: 3,
                buttons: [{
                    type: 'second',
                    count: 1,
                    text: '1s'
                }, {
                    type: 'minute',
                    count: 1,
                    text: '1m'
                }, {
                    type: 'day',
                    count: 1,
                    text: '1d'
                }, {
                    type: 'all',
                    text: 'All'
                }]
            },
            navigator: {
                adaptToUpdatedData: false,
                // ^-- This should be false when loading data asynchronously, 
                // to prevent circular loading
                margin: 5,
                // maskInside: false,
                series: {
                    lineWidth: 0,
                    marker: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: '' // title above chart
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                events: {
                    afterSetExtremes: function(e) {},
                    setExtremes: function(e) {
                        var min = e.min,
                            max = e.max;
                        $('#report').html('Start Time: ' + min + ',<br/> Stop Time: ' + max + ',<br/> e.trigger: ' + e.trigger);
                    }
                },
                plotBands: [{ // mark the weekend
                    color: '#222',
                    from: Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 1, 00),
                    to: Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 7, 00),
                    label: {
                        text: 'Missing Video',
                        style: {
                            color: '#888'
                        }
                    }
                        },
                { // mark the weekend
                    color: '#222',
                    from: Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 11, 00),
                    to: Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 55, 00),
                    label: {
                        text: 'Missing Video',
                        style: {
                            color: '#888'
                        }
                    }
                        }, ],
            },

            yAxis: [{
                height: '60%',
                opposite: false,
                tickInterval: 1,
                tickWidth: 0,
                labels: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        if (inputs[this.value]) {
                            return inputs[this.value].name;
                        }
                    },
                    align: 'right',
                    x: -20,
                    y: 4
                },
                showLastLabel: true
            }, {
                height: '40%',
                top: '60%',
                opposite: false,
                offset: 60,
                lineWidth: 1,
                tickWidth: 0,
                labels: {
                    align: 'right',
                    formatter: function() {
                        return this.value + ' MPH';
                    },
                    x: 52,
                    y: 4
                },
                showLastLabel: true,
                title: {
                    text: 'Speed',
                    align: 'middle',
                    opposite: false,
                    style: {
                        color: '#fff'
                    }
                }
            }],
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            lineWidth: 2
                        }
                    }
                },
                line: {
                    linecap: 'square',
                    marker: {
                        enabled: true // shows markers for all graphs points
                    },
                    point: {
                        events: {
                            click: function() {
                                // let's show the data value of the selected point (on click)
                                $('#click-value').html(Highcharts.dateFormat('%m/%d/%Y at %H:%M:%S', this.x));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },

            series: [{
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        lineWidth: 10
                    }
                },
                lineWidth: 10,
                marker: {
                    enabled: false, // hide markers for interval bars
                    lineWidth: 1
                },
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    align: 'left',
                    formatter: function() {
                        return this.point.options && this.point.options.label;
                    }
                },
                name: '',
                data: status[0].data,
                dataGrouping: {
                    units: groupingUnits
                }
            }, {
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        lineWidth: 10
                    }
                },
                lineWidth: 10,
                marker: {
                    enabled: false, // hide markers for interval bars
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    radius: 5
                },
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    align: 'left',
                    formatter: function() {
                        return this.point.options && this.point.options.label;
                    }
                },
                name: '',
                data: status[1].data,
                dataGrouping: {
                    units: groupingUnits
                }
            }, {
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        lineWidth: 10
                    }
                },
                lineWidth: 10,
                marker: {
                    enabled: false, // hide markers for interval bars
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    radius: 5
                },
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    align: 'left',
                    formatter: function() {
                        return this.point.options && this.point.options.label;
                    }
                },
                name: '',
                data: status[2].data,
                dataGrouping: {
                    units: groupingUnits
                }
            }, {
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        lineWidth: 10
                    }
                },
                lineWidth: 10,
                marker: {
                    enabled: false, // hide markers for interval bars
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    radius: 5
                },
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    align: 'left',
                    formatter: function() {
                        return this.point.options && this.point.options.label;
                    }
                },
                name: '',
                data: status[3].data,
                dataGrouping: {
                    units: groupingUnits
                }
            }, {
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        lineWidth: 10
                    }
                },
                lineWidth: 10,
                marker: {
                    enabled: false, // hide markers for interval bars
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    radius: 5
                },
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    align: 'left',
                    formatter: function() {
                        return this.point.options && this.point.options.label;
                    }
                },
                name: '',
                data: status[4].data,
                dataGrouping: {
                    units: groupingUnits
                }
            }, {
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        lineWidth: 10
                    }
                },
                lineWidth: 10,
                marker: {
                    enabled: false, // hide markers for interval bars
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    radius: 5
                },
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    align: 'left',
                    formatter: function() {
                        return this.point.options && this.point.options.label;
                    }
                },
                name: '',
                data: status[5].data,
                dataGrouping: {
                    units: groupingUnits
                }
            }, {


                name: 'GPS Speed',
                data: [
                    [Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 1, 00), 32],
                    [Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 2, 33), 40],
                    [Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 3, 00), 55],
                    [Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 6, 00), 55],
                    [Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 9, 00), 65],
                    [Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 11, 00), 66],
                    [Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 14, 00), 67],
                    [Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 16, 00), 71],
                    [Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 18, 00), 78],
                    [Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 20, 00), 81],
                    [Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 23, 00), 83],
                    [Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 30, 00), 85],
                    [Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 35, 00), 85],
                    [Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 38, 00), 92],
                    [Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 42, 00), 90],
                    [Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 44, 00), 88],
                    [Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 46, 00), 87],
                    [Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 49, 00), 85],
                    [Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 50, 00), 80],
                    [Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 53, 00), 75],
                    [Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 55, 00), 70],
                    [Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 10, 02, 00), 65],
                    [Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 10, 04, 00), 60],
                    [Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 10, 05, 00), 40],
                    [Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 10, 08, 00), 35]
                ],
                yAxis: 1,
                dataGrouping: {
                    units: groupingUnits
                }
            }, {
                name: 'Patrol Speed',
                data: [
                    [Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 1, 00), 30],
                    [Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 2, 33), 33],
                    [Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 3, 00), 37],
                    [Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 6, 00), 40],
                    [Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 9, 00), 48],
                    [Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 11, 00), 52],
                    [Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 14, 00), 55],
                    [Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 16, 00), 60],
                    [Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 18, 00), 66],
                    [Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 20, 00), 68],
                    [Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 23, 00), 80],
                    [Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 30, 00), 88],
                    [Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 35, 00), 90],
                    [Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 38, 00), 80],
                    [Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 42, 00), 75],
                    [Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 44, 00), 63],
                    [Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 50, 00), 46],
                    [Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 55, 00), 35],
                    [Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 10, 08, 00), 28]
                ],
                yAxis: 1,
                dataGrouping: {
                    units: groupingUnits
                }
            }]
        });
    });
});
$("#slider").slider({
    value: 0,
    min: Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 9, 1, 00),
    max: Date.UTC(2013, 9, 27, 10, 08, 00),
    step: 0.0001,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        //$("#slider1").slider("value", ui.value);
        $("#slider-value").html(ui.value);
    }
}).find('.ui-slider-handle').append('<div class="line"></div>');
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    padding: 10px;
    background: #323334
}
p {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
    color: #aaa;
    font-size: 14px;
}
a, a:visited, a:hover {
    color: #FFDD45;
    text-decoration: underline;
    outline: none;
}
#container {
    min-height: 400px;
    min-width: 310px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
.ui-slider {
    margin: 0 22px 0 110px;
}
.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
    background: url('https://revivemarketing.github.io/images/playhead_top.png') no-repeat 50% 50% !important;
    border:  none !important;
    width: 18px !important;
    height: 20px !important;
    margin-left: -.75em;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
}
#slider.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
    background: url('https://revivemarketing.github.io/images/playhead_bottom.png') no-repeat 50% 50% !important;
}

.ui-slider {
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    background: #6F7073 !important;
    border-color:  #303030 !important;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px #000 inset !important;
    height: .75em;
    border-radius: 0;

}
.line {
    width: 2px;
    background: #FF2600;
    border-left: #9A0900 1px solid;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 8px;
    height: 68px;
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    box-shadow: 1px 0 0 0 #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="http://revivemarketing.github.io/js/highcharts-dark.js"></script>


<div id="container"></div>
<div id="slider"></div>
<p id="slider-value"></p>
<p id="click-value"></p>
<p id="report"></p>
```

Comment: Can you trim your code/example so it will include only necessary code which allow to reproduce the case? [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What exactly do you want to do with the navigator? You can set color for a specific point (columnrange) by setting point's color property - http://jsfiddle.net/2pknpcyL/

Comment: You can find the minimal version here : http://jsfiddle.net/g4KLk/100/